# I can't find the Wind Stone

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind

I got a quest to restore something by making rituals at each Standing Stone in Solthstiem [Bloodmoon DLC]. I have the map which shows the locations of the stones. I did the Tree Stone, but I can't find the Wind Stone.

The location I tried to find the stone is here:

[image: Map showing the locations of 'Water Stone', 'Earth Stone', 'Wind Stone', 'Tree Stone', 'Beast Stone', and 'Sun Stone']

[image: In-game screenshot of the supposed location of the 'Wind Stone']

The Wind Stone is located at where the 2 rivers meet. I tried to find the stone around Garing's House, but no luck. Where is the location of the Wind Stone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is located slightly northwest of Graring's house, west of where the two rivers meet. [Here is a map of the location from UESP.](http://mwmap.uesp.net/?locx=-178242&locy=205540&zoom=16)